# Linking troubles with boost::program_options on OSX using LLVM

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, osx-lion, clang

I'm having trouble getting through the linking phase in my C++ program due to problems with Boost 1.49. I have switched to C++ (`-std=c++11 -libc=libc++`) which works fine for another piece of code (which also uses boost). Boost was installed using homebrew with:

```
brew install boost --universal --with-mpi --with-icu
```

The trouble starts with `boost::program_options`. I get the link errors like this:

```
  "boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int)", referenced from:

... etc. ...

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is a little strange, because doing an nm on the library used reveals, that the symbol appears to be there:

```
nm -U /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib  | grep validate
0000000000019880 - 01 0000   FUN __ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEESaIS7_EEPSsi
0000000000019880 T __ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEESaIS7_EEPSsi
00000000000199e0 - 01 0000   FUN __ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEESaIS7_EEPbi
00000000000199e0 T __ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEESaIS7_EEPbi
0000000000019930 T __ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEPSsi
0000000000019930 - 01 0000   FUN __ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEPSsi
0000000000019c70 - 01 0000   FUN __ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEPbi
0000000000019c70 T __ZN5boost15program_options8validateERNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEPbi
```

I have already tried coaxing homebrew to compile boost with clang instead of gcc by setting CXX and CXX_FLAGS accordingly prior to installation. Not sure I succeeded though.

Pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same question as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to recompile boost with clang and std11 flags, the libc++ library is not binary compatible with the installed libstdc++ in OSX (very early version of gcc prior to changing to gpl3). If your version of clang is 3.1 or over then you can use (otherwise change c++11 to c++0x for earlier versions).

```
./bootstrap.sh
mkdir build
sudo ./bjam toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++" variant=release link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-dir=Build --layout=system --without-mpi --without-python install --prefix=/usr/local
```

You can of course alter any of these as you wish except

> toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++"

This should work for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointer. Thought as much. However, I can't seem to get Boost to compile dynamic libraries for me now. I tried this:

'sudo ./bjam toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" variant=release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-dir=Build --layout=system --without-mpi --without-python install --prefix=/usr/local' 

but got only static ones.

Comment: I finally got the answer through the Boost.Build-Forum:
http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Problems-building-Boost-with-clang-toolchain-and-C-11-td4631556.html

In short:I was missing 'linkflags' when calling bjam:
./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share my (moderately painful) experience of building Boost 1.54 on Mac OS X 10.8.5 with clang 5.0.0 as supplied by Xcode 5.0 . If you want the C++11 features it is very important to compile and link with `clang++`, not with `clang`.

Illustration: take the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string str = "OK";
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can be built with the following command:

`clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ clangstr.cc -o clangstr`

however, if you try this instead:

`clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ clangstr.cc -o clangstr`

then you get linker errors. Note that the `clang` manpage says that the language is selected by the `-std=` option, but this is clearly not enough.

The lesson is that we have to tell `bjam` to explicitly use `clang++` when compiling Boost with C++11 support.

Following [this very useful post](http://cplusplusmusings.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/clang-and-standard-libraries-on-mac-os-x/), I put the following into my `tools/build/v2/user-config.jam`:

```
using clang : 11
    : "/usr/bin/clang++"
    : <cxxflags>"-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -ftemplate-depth=512" <linkflags>"-stdlib=libc++"
    ;
```

Then I ran `./b2 clean`, then I built Boost with the following command:

```
mkdir -p build/clangstage/
./b2 -j8 --build-dir=build --stagedir=build/clangstage toolset=clang-11 define=BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED variant=release threading=multi address-model=64 stage
```

This builds the 64-bit static and dynamic libraries with multithreading support. If you need a different set then change the command above accordingly.