# Are g++ and clang++ 100% binary compatible?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, abi

And if not, what things are incompatible?

Assume that both use the same standard library implementation (for example, libstdc++).

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11274684/985296) provide an answer to your question?

Comment: I don't think they are. Different compiler implementions ususally introduce different ABI's. Though I'm not sure at all, interesting question ...

Comment: What does "binary compatible" mean, anyway? The C ABI is practically universal, but beyond that...

Comment: @stefan That answer is from 2012, the fundamental facts might have changed since then.

Comment: @cmaster: Then the answers should be updated (or at least dated).  New posts should still  be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @cmaster Then it should be updated. But that also answers it in a way: If you can't be sure that things don't change across different versions of one compiler, you can never rely on two different compilers being compatible

Comment: I talk about C++ ABI (name mangling, rtti, exceptions, vtables and so on). It is said in documentation that C ABI is compatible, but I don't know if C++ is.

Comment: You should assume it is not ABI compatible.

Comment: clang++ links with g++ compiled libraries (on x86-64 linux, at least) in general. But I'm sure it's possible to find bugs - like with any large compiler implementation.