# Googletest: CLANG compiles where GCC fails

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, static-libraries, googletest

Here is a very simple script using gtest (saved in file gt.cpp)

```
#include<gtest/gtest.h>

double timesTwo(double x){return x*2;}

TEST(testTimesTwo, integerTests){EXPECT_EQ(6, timesTwo(3));}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The script compiles fine with CLANG (`Apple clang version 11.0.3`)

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -lgtest gt.cpp -o gt
```

but fails with GCC (`g++ (GCC) 10.2.0`)

```
g++ -std=c++17 -lgtest gt.cpp -o gt

gt.cpp:2:9: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include<gtest/gtest.h>
      |
```

Using the `-H` option in CLANG, I see the header file is included from `/usr/local/include`. Also, I can find the `libgtest.a` file in `/usr/local/bin/`. So, I did

```
g++ -std=c++17 gt.cpp -o gt -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgtest
```

and got a long list of undefined symbols starting with

```
Macavity:test remi$ g++ -std=c++17  gt.cpp -o gt -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgtest
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN7testing8internal9EqFailureEPKcS2_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_b", referenced from:
      __ZN7testing8internal18CmpHelperEQFailureIidEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_ in ccrUwUPO.o
  "__ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE4findEcm", referenced from:
      __ZN7testing8internal11SplitStringERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEcPNS1_6vectorIS7_NS5_IS7_EEEE in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      __ZN7testing8internalL21FormatDeathTestOutputERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "__ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE7compareEmmPKcm", referenced from:
```

Can you help me figure out why `GCC` fails to compile here?

Comment: `-L/usr/local/include/` <-- Are you sure that's where the library file is (and not in e.g. `usr/local/lib`)?

Comment: The `which` command is for seeing the location of an executable, and is not necessarily related to the locations of library headers or library binaries.

Comment: @Michael The first line outputted by `clang++ -H ...` is `. /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h`. Now that is for the header file. I am not sure about the library file.

Comment: That's the header/include file. I'm talking about the library (i.e. `libgtest.a` or whatever it's called).

Comment: @Michael Yes, you are right the library is probably included form `/usr/local/lib` (I confirm I can find `libgtest.a` over there). I also tried `g++ -std=c++17  gt.cpp -o gt -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgtest` but it also return linker errors (undefined symbols).

Comment: I edited the post to simplify this discussion of where files are located, now that I understand it better thanks to your comments.

Comment: Problem is that library build by `gcc` is used by `clang`. There are some differences in case of C++ which makes this problematic see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11274684/1387438

Comment: @MarekR `clang` manages to compile while `gcc` does not. If I unedrstand what you are saying this is because `googletest` was compiled using `clang` on my machine. Is that right? If I reinstall `googletest`, comoiling with `gcc` (if I can figure out how to do that because I see no mention of the compiler in the makefile), then it should work with `GCC` (but maybe not with `clang`).

Comment: Problem persists in both directions. Do demanbgling of this messages and note liker complains it can't find symbols for `std::string` needed by `gtest`. Different implementations of `std::string` leads to different name mangling and this symbol can't be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is this error message passed through a http://demangler.com/

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
      _testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int, double>(char const*, char const*, int const&, double const&) in ccrUwUPO.o
  "_std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::find(char, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      _testing::internal::SplitString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >*) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
      _testing::internal::FormatDeathTestOutput(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o)
  "_std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
```

Note that second and third error complains that linker can't find implementation of: `std::string::find(char, unsigned long)` and `std::string::compare(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) const`.

Those are parts of standard C++ library. Since `std::string` is template some parts of it are part of library which uses that template, but is some cases it can be part of C++ runtime.

Now I suspect that you compiled `gtest` with a `clang` and try use it when building test with `gcc` (or vice versa). A bit different implementations of `std::string` on both compilers lead to divergence in available symbols.

So please make sure that gtest and test application are build with same compiler.

Here is some description of [binary compatibility between gcc and clang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11274684/1387438). There are some hints what problem is, but it is not very formal (maybe I will find better document).